# VB.NET Socket Send and Receive

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to ping a message to a server and get a message back with a numeric value of total players on the server. Unfortunately the code below freezes unless I remove a piece of the code seen below.

```
Public Shared Function SocketSendReceive(server As String, port As Integer) As String
    'Set up variables and String to write to the server. 
    Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.ASCII
    Dim request As String = (DoubleChar(Len(Chr(35))) + Chr(CheckSum(Chr(35)) * 20 Mod 194) + Chr(0) + Chr(35))
    Dim bytesSent As [Byte]() = ascii.GetBytes(request)
    Dim bytesReceived(255) As [Byte]

    ' Create a socket connection with the specified server and port. 
    Dim s As Socket = ConnectSocket(server, port)

    If s Is Nothing Then
        Return "0"
    End If
    ' Send request to the server.
    s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0)

    ' Receive the server  home page content. 
    Dim bytes As Int32

    ' Read the first 256 bytes. 
    Dim page As [String] = "0"

    ' The following will block until the page is transmitted. 
    Do
        bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0)
        page = page + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes)
    Loop While bytes > 0
    Return page
End Function
```

As I remove this part of the code:

```
    Do
        bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0)
        page = page + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes)
    Loop While bytes > 0
```

The ping goes through but does not return the value. Could somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why `[Byte]` and `[String]`? They work fine without the brackets...

Comment: If your data just so happens to be a multiple of 256 bytes, then it will block and never return. Try `Loop While s.Available > 0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is making it crash, I had the similar problem. What you got to do is make your server multithreaded. What you do here is loop through the code a infinite amount of times, which is making the current thread to freeze. If you add another thread it will work. Google (mutlithreaded socket programming)